# Add transition effect in a slideshow

Tags: xcode, ios5, slideshow, effects, photo-gallery

I'm trying to add a transition effect to my slideshow: here's my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSXMLParser *photoParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"http://localhost/index.xml"]];
[photoParser setDelegate:(id)self];
[photoParser parse];

currentImage = 0;

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[photos objectAtIndex:0]];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector(handleTimer:)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: YES];
}

- (void) handleTimer: (NSTimer *) timer {
currentImage++;
if ( currentImage >= photos.count )
    currentImage = 0;

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[photos objectAtIndex:currentImage]];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict { 
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"photo"]) {
    [photos addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
}
}
```

I think I should use

```
[UIView transitionFromView:currentView toView:nextView duration:1.0 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:nil];
```

but I don't how to fill the transitionFRomView: and toView: fields. I only have one view

Thanks for your help

Comment: I can't test it now but I will as soon as I can and I'll let you know. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` for which the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW112) says:

> You can use this block to add, remove, show, or hide subviews of the specified view.

This is an example of how you can use that method:

```
- (void) handleTimer: (NSTimer *) timer {
    currentImage++;
    if (currentImage >= photos.count) currentImage = 0;

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[photos objectAtIndex:currentImage]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]
   [UIView transitionWithView:containerView
       duration:2
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
       animations:^{
           [imgView removeFromSuperview];
           imgView = // create a new image view
           [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
           [containerView addSubview:toView];
       } completion:NULL];
}
```

Where `containerView` is the parent view of `imgView` and most likely is `self.view`.

Comment: It works just replacing containerView with self.view , imgView =           [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]]; with [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]]; and [containerView addSubview:toView]; with [self.view addSubview:imgView]; Great! Do you know ho to add buttons to go back, forward and pause the presentation? Or should I submit another question?

Comment: @Enzoses - Where do you want to add those buttons? And yes, it is better to ask this in another question so that you can add more information.

Comment: I'd like to show controls to allow users to decide to skip a photo, or to go back or to pause to a particular one. I think they should be placed in the same view, or maybe I'd create a "MainView" with the buttons, and inside it the slideshowView